# ng-table grouping does not work when exactly same data is assigned using rest service output

Tags: json, angularjs, ngtable

I am facing an interesting issue. The ng-table groups works correctly when the input data is hardcoded which is same as data which comes from rest service json.

**Below hardcoded json works :**

```
var data = [{name: "Moroni", age: 50, role: 'Administrator'},
            {name: "Tiancum", age: 43, role: 'Administrator'},
            {name: "Jacob", age: 27, role: 'Administrator'},
            {name: "Nephi", age: 29, role: 'Moderator'},
            {name: "Enos", age: 34, role: 'User'},
            {name: "Tiancum", age: 43, role: 'User'},              
            {name: "Enos", age: 34, role: 'User'}];
```

**This does not work**

```
 var data = response;
```

I debugged response and it is exactly same as my hardcoded json data. I am unable to figure out what is the issue.

I have seen ng-table documentation and followed the same. My html and js code is similar to - http://bazalt-cms.com/ng-table/example/13

My code is exactly similar to above example 13 link. Just I am calling a service and getting similar data. (Plunker link - http://plnkr.co/edit/becd3D)

**I am still facing same issue. Can anyone please help.**

Please help. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Please see here http://plnkr.co/edit/fsNx1h?p=preview

just move your $scope.tableParams into call back function after you get data from server.

```
 $http.get('data.json').then(function(response){
   var data = response.data
    $scope.tableParams = new ngTableParams({
        page: 1,            // show first page
        count: 10          // count per page
    }, {
        groupBy: function(item) {
            return 'First letter "' + item.name[0] + '"';
        },
        total: data.length,
        getData: function($defer, params) {

            var orderedData = params.sorting() ?
                    $filter('orderBy')(data, $scope.tableParams.orderBy()) :
                    data;

            $defer.resolve(orderedData.slice((params.page() - 1) * params.count(), params.page() * params.count()));
        }
    });

    });
})
```

Comment: Same idea as my solution, but a bit more simple (to implement, and to understand), since you're passing the entire `tableParams`. I'd probably go with that.

Comment: My $scope.tableParams is already in success callback function. Still it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

I'll try avoiding the "link only"-type of answer, but this is so contrived, I find it hard to understand myself, let alone explain it.

The example given on the website is not using any sort of callback, don't know if it is a mistake or not.

Here's how I proceeded :

- There's an example on the website showing AJAX loading into ngTable.
- There's another example showing how to group the data.

I mixed them together. Here's a [**working demo**](http://plnkr.co/edit/160FxOVrJlxBX5XeyZFK?p=preview).

From what I understand, the whole `getData` function needs to get everything together, either asynchronously or hardcoded. So you'll have to pass it the data, but some configuration parameters aswell :

```
getData: function($defer, params) {

    // ajax request to api
    Api.get(params.url(), function(data) {
        $timeout(function() {

            // update table params
            params.total(data.total);

            // set new data
            $defer.resolve(data.result);

        }, 500);
    });
}
```